# Create layout using only constraint layout and text view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am new to android and constraint layout, can you please help me create this [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhRgD.png) using only Constraint Layout and Text Views? Don't bother with text/color, just the layout itself.

This is what I have so far, layout seems ok but not quite like in the picture. I don't know if just the different resolution or aspect ratio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView45"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/blackk"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView49"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView47"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView46"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView45" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView46"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView48"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/Accent"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView46"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView45" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView49"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView50"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView48"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView47"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView45" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView50"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView46"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView48"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView47"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView49" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should use nested linear layouts instead of a constraint one.

Comment: @SujalKumar linear layout not allowed in this one.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yeah but since he is just starting, won't linear layouts be easier to understand from a learning point of view?

Comment: @SujalKumar Task specifies using only constraint layout and text views. I could solve this with lin. layouts no problem

Comment: It looks like the size of the text in your image and the size in your layout differ. You have `wrap_content` for "textView47" and "textView48". If you change the text size to something larger, you will get closer to what you want. How will the text vary in your view and what do you _want_ to happen when the text does change. Do you want the four middle boxes to remain the same size or something different?

Answer (score 0):

Did some modifications in the margins of these two. Now, the layout is looking similar to the one in the image you showed:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView49"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView50"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView48"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView47"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView45" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView50"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView46"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView48"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView47"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView49" />
```

You can further increase the margins but that's upto you.

Edit: I would suggest you playing with **layout_constraintHeight_percent** attribute to solve those height irregularities.